# PHP Page generating a 500 internal server error

Tags: php, iis, twilio

I have a PHP page that receives incoming POST data an updates a CRM system which is working fine, however I'm getting a 500 internal server error even thought it's working fine. I suspect this has something to do with the last few lines of the PHP page which need to output an empty  to the calling server (Twilio). Here's a summary of the last part of the page:

```
<?php

// code to create record in company CRM system

 header("content-type: text/xml");
 echo "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n";
?>
 <Response>
 </Response>
```

It's running on a Windows Server 2008 machine with PHP 5.3.27. There's nothing in the log files that explains what the issue might be here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't put your header in an `echo` block. It opens up a potential can of worms. I would move it outside the PHP block

```
<?php
    header("content-type: text/xml");
?>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <Response>
 </Response>
```